# PCRE Patterns Regular Expression for Digit Followed by any number of digits and forwards slashes no double slashes ending with digit?

Tags: php, regex

I have the following so far:

```
'#^[0-9]([0-9]|/)*$[0-9]#'
```

I am using `#` as the delimiter as forward slashes are in the pattern.

It is not working correctly however, it needs to start with a digit and contain digits and slashes (no double slashes) and end with a digit.

Comment: Quick help. I'm working on a complete answer, but to end in a digit put the $ before the last #, as in     [0-9]$#'

Comment: Can you provide a few example inputs and wanted outputs? What should `12//3` return?

Comment: For characters you don't want [^ ]    (put the characters after the carrot. Example this means NOT the letter w:  [^w]

Comment: Which is it "any number of digits and forward slashes" or "it needs to start with a digit and contain digits and slashes"???

Comment: Is it allowed that it contains no slashes? Is it allowed that it contains a single digit?

Comment: Quantifiers: `*` zero or more of something. `+` one or more of something.

Comment: "start with a digit *and* contain **digits** *and* **slashes**"  No order is specified.

Comment: @AnthonyRutledge Please don't downvote I haven't responded as I was AFK. It can contain any number of digits or slashes, but slashes must be singular (there cannot be two or more next to each other), must start and end with a digit.

Comment: @StevieG : Is the number zero (0) an acceptable number of slashes `/`? In other words, would a string like this be allowed `123456789`. In RE's, "any number" can mean none (i.e. 0).

Comment: @AnthonyRutledge: There should be at least 1.

Comment: @StevieG That being said, my answer is the most correct if the syntax pans out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this simple regex (the [online demo](http://regex101.com/r/hZ7jA8) shows you which strings match or fail):

```
^\d(?:(?!//)[\d/])+\d$
```

**Code Sample**

```
$regex = "~^\d(?:(?!//)[\d/])+\d$~";
if(preg_match($regex,$string,$m)) echo $m[0];
```

**Explain Regex**

```
^                        # the beginning of the string
\d                       # digits (0-9)
(?:                      # group, but do not capture (1 or more times
                         # (matching the most amount possible)):
  (?!                    #   look ahead to see if there is not:
    //                   #     '//'
  )                      #   end of look-ahead
  [\d/]                  #   any character of: digits (0-9), '/'
)+                       # end of grouping
\d                       # digits (0-9)
$                        # before an optional \n, and the end of the
                         # string
```

Comment: Good tip. Very good. However, his pattern is looking for `/` and the site seems to see these as delimiters by default. Know how to change the delimiter?

Comment: @AnthonyRutledge You can see in my code sample that the delimiter is `~` @Downvoter why the downvote?

Comment: How can anyone's answer be voted up when the question and description are at odds with one another?

Answer (score 1):

I forget how to change the delimiter. With some commands / languages you have to start the delimieter like this \# at the beginning to use # as the delimiter. This may not be the case for you.

I should probably look up my RE's first. But here's an honest whack at it.

```
'#^[0-9][0-9/[^(//)]]+[0-9]$#'    //greedy


'#^[0-9][0-9/[^(//)]]+?[0-9]$#'   //non-greedy
```

Comment: Based on the description of the problem, not the title.

Comment: My syntax might be off, but the notion fits the problem description best.

Answer (score 0):

My solution:

```
'#^[0-9]+(/[0-9]+)*$#'
```

**Edit**
If at least one slash must be present:

```
'#^[0-9]+(/[0-9]+)+$#'
```

or with non collecting parentheses and `\d` instead of `[0-9]`:

```
'#^\d+(?:/\d+)*$#'
```

Comment: `\d`'s would make it look a lot better.

Comment: Oh, indeed. I use regular expressions in many environments, and not all of them understand \d, therefore I am got used to using [0-9] instead.

Comment: \d would not make it more efficient.

Comment: @tzunghaor : I'm not certain you have exclude the possibility of a double slash:  `//`

Comment: every slash must be followed by at least one digit. I even tried it for some trivial double slashes.

Comment: `(/[0-9]+)*` Translation: "Zero or more of at least one `/` followed by a digit. However, there must be digits and slashes, so zero of something does not fit. Or, am I twisted up?

Comment: @tzunghaor Yes, good show. I see that now (duh)! Now, if the title of the question matched his description of the problem...

Comment: Hey, but who said that numbers must follow a slash? The requirement is only that there be slashes and numbers, but no double slashes. Order is not specified. `123456789/0` should still be valid, but it's not with the RE you made.

Comment: @AnthonyRutledge Yes it is. I tried. Since the last character must be a digit, all slashes are followed by at least one digit.

Comment: @tzunghaor. So it is, but what about `123456789`. There are no slashes, but there must be, according to the problem *description*.

Comment: Since you are saying this `'#^[0-9]`, I believe the `+` the end is not actually doing anything useful, but I get why you put it there.

Comment: The `+` in your opening patter is not necessary.
'#^[0-9]`+` . The `*` in the second part does not fulfill the requirement of there being at least one `/`.

Answer (score 0):

You should use something like this:

```
%^\d+(?:/\d+)+$%usD
```

Explanation:

```
%               # beginning of the pattern
    ^           # beginning of the string
        \d+     # it starts with at least one digit
        (?:     # beginning of a non-capturing group which contains
            /   # a single slash
            \d+ # followed by at least one digit, so it will never match double slashes
        )       # end of non-capturing group
        +       # the non-capturing group should match once or more
    $           # end of the string
%               # end of the pattern
    u           # unicode string
    s           # the "." matches all characters including "\n"
    D           # the "$" matches the end of the string and not "\n" (end of the line)
```